# Update only date without modifying time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have data in my database table as

```
last_updated_product
01/Jan/1899 6:25:01 AM
01/Jan/1899 6:25:02 AM
```

How can I update only the date part with sysdate without modifying the time part? 
Expected outout

```
21/Aug/2013 6:25:01 AM
21/Aug/2013 6:25:02 AM
```

`last_updated_product` column data type is defined as `date`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use midnight on the current day, and add on the time part from the original value:

```
trunc(sysdate) + (last_updated_product - trunc(last_updated_product))
```

`trunc()` gives you the date with the time component set to 00:00:00, so `date - trunc(date)` gives you just the original time component, as a number (fraction of a day) as per the [datetime arithmetic rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168). That number can then be added on to midnight today.

Not sure if you're actually updating the table or just doing this in a query, but it's the same calculation either way.

Answer (score 2):

You can either work out the time portion and add in the date you want, for instance:

```
update my_table
   set last_updated_product = 
              to_date('21/Aug/2013', 'dd/Mon/yyyy')
              -- difference between the start of the day and the time
              + (last_updated_product - trunc(last_updated_product))
```

The extra brackets are to ensure the query works according to the operator order of preference as you can't add a date to a date but you can add an interval. The brackets ensure that `last_updated_product - trunc(last_updated_product)` is evaluated before  the addition takes place.

or convert it to a character, concatenate it to the date and then convert it back to a date.

```
update my_table
   set last_updated_product = 
             to_date('21/Aug/2013' || to_char(last_updated_product, 'hh24:mi:ss')
                     , 'dd/Mon/yyyyhh24:mi:ss')
```

e.g.

```
create table my_table ( last_updated_product date );

Table created.

insert into my_table values (sysdate - 100);

1 row created.

update my_table
   set last_updated_product =
          to_date('21/Aug/2013', 'dd/Mon/yyyy')
          + (last_updated_product - trunc(last_updated_product))
       ;

1 row updated.

select * from my_table;

LAST_UPDATED_PRODUC
-------------------
2013/08/21 08:13:57
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I will try this approach.

Comment: Yes I tried your first approach, it worked like a charm. Unfortunately I did not have enough credits to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   update <table>
      set last_updated_product = 
               last_updated_product 
             - trunc(last_updated_product )
             + trunc(sysdate)
    where <condition>
        ;
```